# Doing I/O in NASM programs on Windows 7 platform

Tags: nasm

Please give me a NASM 2.07 sample program which reads and prints a character. Also please tell the commands to assemble and link it. My compiler is Borland C++ 5.0(bcc32) and OS is Windows 7. Where can I get tutorials about I/O in NASM with Windows 7?